# Disable highlight in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, xml, listview, expandablelistview

I had been trying to disable the highlight in a ExpandableListView. I tried setting the next drawable as background, but this didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@color/_GREY_Weak"/>

<item android:drawable="@color/_GREY_Weak"
    android:state_pressed="true" />

<item android:drawable="@color/_GREY_Weak"
    android:state_selected="true" />

<item android:drawable="@color/_GREY_Weak"
    android:state_focused="true" />

<item android:drawable="@color/_GREY_Weak"
    android:state_checked="true" />

<item android:drawable="@color/_GREY_Weak"
    android:state_long_pressable="true" />

<item android:drawable="@color/_GREY_Weak"
    android:state_hovered="true" />

<item android:drawable="@color/_GREY_Weak"
    android:state_expanded="true" />
</selector>
```

I tried setting each state drawable as that color, @null or transparent, but still the same. Here are some screenshots of my issue. I want to get rid of that highlight in the childrens as in the parent.

[image]

[image]

I also triead setting the property drawingCacheHint in the ExpandableListView xml with no luck.

Comment: The orange highlight effect is a style on the ExpandableListView. You need to override the ExpandablelistView style. Have you tried android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" in ExpandableListView xml

Comment: Thanks that did the trick!. If you want post your comment as answer so I can check it as usefull.

Comment: Glad it worked. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding

```
 android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
```

in ExpandableListView xml

Or override the ExpandableListView style.